# Why does Zoom slow down and hang up after about 20 minutes of working in Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, zoom-meeting

After upgrading and updating everything on my HP Pavilion AMD laptop, ZOOM on my Ubuntu 20.04 will run for 15 to 20 minutes then hang up with the "Wait or Force Quit" option.  Wait eventually gets it back working, but then it is very slow and doesn't update the images in real time anymore.  Sound is usually ok, but eventually, Zoom stops responding to things like mute or unmute or attempts to type into the chat window. At that point, it takes a long time to leave the zoom meeting and shut down zoom.  Closing Zoom and re-starting it, then rejoining the meeting works for another 15 or 20 minutes before the problem comes up again.

Comment: The "slow down" description seems a lot like swapping. Swapping occurs when you run out of RAM, and the system tries to use disk space instead of crashing. Look up how to use the `free` command to determine if you are swapping. Next time it occurs, use `free` to check for swapping.

Comment: Right.  It might be that zoom is tying up more and more ram as it goes along.  My system has 8 GB of RAM so it would take a while if nothing else is running. I'll look into that.  Thanks.

Comment: Edit your question and show me `free -h` after the system slows down. Also `sysctl vm.swappiness` and `swapon -s`. Start comments to me with @heynnema or I'll miss them.

Comment: I wrote this script <nl>

sudo sync <nl>

sudo sysctl -w vm.drop_caches=3 <nl>

sudo sync <nl>

When I run free before and after this script, it does seem to show that the script slows down the rate at which available memory goes down, but eventually, I have to reboot my laptop to get memory back to normal.  Seems Zoom fails at memory management.   Also, throughout the Zoom session, the CPU fraction used by Zoom slowly keeps creeping up.   When I save a comment, it looks like NewLine characters ignored.  They show up when I edit. Am I missing something?